# Real Time alerts on a big and constantly changing dataset

Tags: database, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, real-time

I have a huge dataset which I have to monitor for anomalies and send alerts. The closest example to what I am trying to do it as follows.

Lets say there is a stocks table in a relational database:

```
stocks:
    id
    date
    stock_name
    price
```

Lets say there are a million stocks we are dealing with. During the day, the price of the stock keeps updating based on the constant and frequent live feeds. At the end of the day, the last recorded price for each stock is the closing price for that day. Next day, we **add** another million records to the table and start working on it again.

Suppose users can configure alerts like:
`"When AAPL moves more than 10% than its average for past 10 days, alert me"`
or `"When any stock moves more than 10% of its average for past 10 days, alert me"`

There can be 100s of alerts by different users that we need to cater to. Constant polling and trying to match alerts at a regular interval isn't practical.

How would you implement it? If we need to go the big data route, what kind of datastore/caching are conducive for such problems. I understand that this is a pretty open ended question, but I am looking for a direction on how similar problems are solved and what toolsets are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for a stream processor, such as [Apache Flink](http://flink.apache.org) or [Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org). Flink and Storm are both scalable distributed systems. They ingest streams of data in and analyze the data with continuously running programs at low latency (hundreds of ms, depending on program complexity). For example, you can filter streams, define time windows to compute aggregates over a certain time range (the last 30 minutes or 10 days), or combine multiple data streams.